# How to rebuild cq5 libs?

Tags: aem, crx

I have ACCIDENTALLY deleted the libs folder from CRXDE Lite (this is the folder standing near var, etc, apps, content... etc). How to rebuild it? new start of the server did not help. I hope somebody can help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Start a fresh CQ instance
2. Open Package Manager (relative path: `/crx/packmgr/index.jsp`) on the new instance
3. Create new package and add `/libs` to its filter
4. Build and download the package
5. Open Package Manager on the damaged instance
6. Upload & install package

Answer (score 0):

If you want your current CQ instance, then, in a new folder copy AEM jar and start it in different port number(say 4503). Once start go to package manager create a package by adding a rule with /libs and then download.
package manager url(port number) : http://localhost:4503/crx/packmgr/index.jsp

Once download, upload this package into your AEM instance running in 4502.